# Error installing "@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection" npm package

Tags: windows, tensorflow, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I am encountering an issue while trying to install the "@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection" npm package for face landmarks detection using TensorFlow. I have followed the installation instructions provided, but I keep running into an error. Here are the steps I've taken and the error message I'm receiving:

I ran the command npm install @tensorflow/tfjs @tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection.
The installation started, but after a while, it failed with the following error message:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: face-crop-app-be@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl@4.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl
npm ERR!   peer @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl@"^4.4.0" from @tensorflow-models/face-detection@1.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@tensorflow-models/face-detection
npm ERR!     peer @tensorflow-models/face-detection@"~1.0.0" from @tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection@1.0.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection
npm ERR!       @tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection@"^1.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl@"^3.12.0" from @tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection@1.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection
npm ERR!   @tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection@"^1.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

I use NVM with using node 16.13.2 and NPM 9.6.7. I also tried reinstalling dependencies, but the error persists.

Can someone please guide me on how to resolve this issue? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM doesn't support conflicting version numbers of imported libraries. Use Yarn instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. Tried several things anything resolve this issue. create a new project with yarn instead of npm using the same code. worked perfectly fine.